# Humans hate pows and programmers hate humans - let's connect them!

Tags: code-golf

## Background

The task is simple but every programmer has implemented it at least once. Stackoverflow has a lot of samples, but are they short enough to win?

## Problem story

You're a grumpy programmer who was given the task of implementing file size input for the users. Since users don't use bytes everyone will just enter "1M", "1K", "3G", "3.14M" - but you need bytes! So you write a program to do the conversion.

Then your manager hands you dozens of user reports with complaints about weird large numbers in file size input. It seems you'll need to code the reverse conversion too.

## What do you need to do?

Here's the trick: you should implement two-way conversion in single piece of code. Two separate functions used as needed? Nah, that's too simple - let's make one, short one!

For the purposes of this challenge, "kilobyte" means 1024 bytes, "megabyte" means 1024*1024 = 1048576 bytes, and "gigabyte" means 1024*1024*1024 = 1073741824 bytes.

## Test data

```
Input   -> Output  
5       -> 5  
1023    -> 1023  
1024    -> 1K  
1K      -> 1024  
1.5K    -> 1536  
1536    -> 1.5K  
1048576 -> 1M  
1M      -> 1048576
```

## Rules

- Test value will not exceed 2*1024*1024*1024 or 2G
- The following postfixes are used by users: K for kilobytes, M for megabytes, G for gigabytes
- Code is not required to work with negative numbers
- Do not use any external libraries (e.g. `BCMath` in PHP) besides bundled ones (e.g. `math.h`)
- Standard loopholes are disallowed
- Code should not produce anything on stderr
- Your program can take input and produce output using [standard methods].(http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: Usually programs don't take variable input and output...

Comment: And why do you want us to convert bytes back to postfixed numbers? Your question stated that "you need bytes!"

Comment: @Dr.EmmettBrown: In real application it wouldn't make sense, but hey - it's code-golf. If number is <1024 you should leave it as-is, for 1024 you should convert to 1k, for 1k you should convert to 1024 ;)
I slightly edited rules regarding data i/o.

Comment: 1024 is not a kilobyte (k); it's a kibibyte (KiB). Similarly, 1048576 is not a megabyte (M); it's a mebibyte (MiB).

Comment: @killer129 As it stands this two-way conversion would be a little ridiculous.

Comment: @ToddLehman: As for lowercase "k" I have to agree with you, but KB/MB/GB are commonly used to denote size of files. Why? Probably due to JDEC.

Comment: @Dr.EmmettBrown: Implementing it one way is easy - try to do it two-way ;)

Comment: Despite perhaps not being useful for real life, this challenge is well-specified and a non-trivial task. I for one think it just needs a little more polish on the wording. FYI, @kiler129, for future challenges you can get all these kinks worked out ahead of time by posting in the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first.

Comment: @DLosc: Thank you for recommendation - I didn't know about it :) It's 1:21AM in my tz and I was implementing [again] conversion from and to human readable values and "the magic programmer vortex" sucked me into THAT weird thinking "what if..." ;)

Comment: I edited your post for grammar and clarity. The main thing I think you need to decide is the I/O methods. As TheDoctor said, variables aren't a [default I/O method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). You're free to override those defaults for your question if you like, but I'd say there's no reason to. However, I'll leave that decision up to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51928/format-the-given-number-of-bytes-to-a-human-readable-format

Comment: @DLosc: I appreciate you since english is not my mother tongue. After little thinking and reading poll you linked I think it's safer to stick with default one, since it's easier for everyone to verify code and there's no confusion if variable counts etc.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Actually I seen that challenge and it was easy - I raised the bar ;)

Comment: @kiler129 — Sure, those were common in the 70s and 80s. But the new IEC units have been around for 17 years now (since 1998) and a US NIST requirement for 7 years (since 2008), so people should really be using them instead of the old units (which were always wrong anyway). Just my 2¢.

Comment: how many decimal digits do you want? 1024 = 1k, 1025 = 1.0 k or 1k? 1526398 = 1.45568656921 M....

Comment: There exist different sets of standards. Some still use the power-2 convention on the base-10 prefixes - as such, I would say that it is excusable here.

Comment: So we should implement function or whole program?

Comment: @Zereges: Only the conversion algorithm which from given input produces correct output.

Comment: Can we take string in one way and number another way?

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>204</s> 190 bytes

This is my first ever codegolf.

```
s=raw_input()
p=' KMG'
if s[-1]<='9':
 e=0;r=int(s)
 while r>=1024:r/=1024.0;e+=1
else:
 e=p.index(s[-1]);r=eval(s[:-1])
 while e>0:r*=1024;e-=1
print(`r`if r%1!=0 else`int(r)`)+p[e].strip()
```

Comment: [-25 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY3LCsIwFET3@YpsJEmLtakPsBq3LsQvKMUUeksDJYabaPHrY9PVwDBzjvuF8W2rGL3Cbn4Z6z6BC@IUo4/nnRFQJTED9c1WtlfFzqwmFJWxgXtB6DyaCSjelCyrQ427NYvyArmSBCYP6xq@3cR9Uy8IkaVFlrliMLbnK3axYQJq1IsJNzIddWpQaJG7BtrCBzSOixiPp331Bw "Python 2 – Try It Online"). works by replacing the loop with the power operator (`**`) and changing the `r%1!=0` to `r%1`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 60 bytes

```
l:" KMG"Fi1,4Ia>=Y1024x:(a/:y).l@ix|aR`.+([KMG])`_*y**(l@?B)
```

Takes input from the command line (assigned to `a` variable) and outputs to stdout.

**Ungolfed version:**

```
l : " KMG"
Y 1024
F i 1,4
 I a>=y {
  a /: y
  x : a . l@i
 }
x | a R `.+([KMG])` {a*y**(l@?b)}
```

**Algorithm:**

- For `i` from 1 through 3:

  - If `a >= 1024`, this is a byte value that needs to be converted to a larger unit:

    - Divide `a` by 1024
    - Set `x` to be the current value of `a` concatenated with the current unit
- If `x` was set by the previous step, output it. Otherwise, `a` was less than 1024 (with a possible unit suffix), so:

  - Do a regex replacement with a function on `a` if it has one of `KMG` at the end: translate the letter to the appropriate power of 1024 and multiply the number by the result.
  - For values less than 1024 without a suffix, this leaves the value unchanged.

Comment: What is pip? Can you put a link or something?

Comment: Sure! Pip is a golfing language that I made.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>144</s> 106 bytes

```
n=>((G=(M=(K=2<<9)<<10)<<10),+n>0?n<K?n:n<M?n/K+'K':n<G?n/M+'M':n/G+'G':eval(n.replace(/[KMG]/,m=>'*'+m)))
```

This can definitely be shortened, and will do later. Just wanted to get something ugly out there ;)

Answer (score 1):

### C <del>206</del> 183 bytes

Got rid of as much as I could.

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
main(y,z)char**z;{char*i="KMG";float f=atof(*++z);while(*++*z)y=**z;if(y>57){do f*=1024;while(y!=*i++);y=0;}else while(f>1023)y=*i++,f/=1024;printf("%.1lf%c",f,y);}
```

#### Output

```c
Input: 1023
Output: 1023.0

Input: 1M
Output: 1048576.0

Input: 1048576
Output: 1.0M
```

#### Explanation

```c
#include <stdlib.h> //needed for atof()
main(y,z)char **z; //y will hold the size indicator
{
    char *i="KMG";//holds the characters for the size indicators
    float f=atof(*++z); //get the number from the string

    while(*++*z) //loops through the string
        y=**z;
    if(y>57) //57 is ASCII for 9
    {
        do f*=1024;
        while(y!=*i++); //loop through until we hit the correct size
        y=0;
    }
    else
        while(f>1023) //loop through until number is less than 1024
            y=*i++,f/=1024; 
    printf("%.1lf%c",f,y); //print number and size character 
}
```

Comment: [136B](https://tio.run/##PYxLCsIwFACvEgMtSfrERusHQrp1IR4ivPTZQEylLbgQzx7FgtuZYXB9Q8wZezeqYPnleuaA4M3dhSTki@LgZkYmkJjQJRK8oAI5lAQlylZLPzBSVtfbxjz7EDuBK6tCVUnTxaljC6P2G@yk/xmgzdI/xpDm/5HAS/POWdfNaX88fAA)

Comment: @l4m2, nice, you could edit that into the answer if you want (or post your own)

Answer (score 0):

## Python2 199 bytes

this is silly but it works (ignoring the decimal precision question) as long as you have dozens of gigabytes of RAM. dont run it otherwise, your machine might freeze and lockup. The first thing it does is allocate a 2gigabyte array of integers.

```
n,bn={'K':2**10,'M':2**20,'G':2**30},range(2**30+1)
for i in bn:
 for j in 'KMG':
  if i>=n[j]: bn[i]=str(float(i/n[j]))+j 
def f(i):
 if i[-1] in 'KMG': return n[i[-1]]*float(i[:-1])
 return bn[int(i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 91 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,m)=>n<1024?n+['.KMG'[m]]:n>0?f(n/1024,-~m):eval(n.replace(/.$/,'*32**$&',K=2,M=4,G=6))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9NDoIwEIX3nIKFkRZKQf40xOLSRcMJCEaChWigEDCElVdHSkWdzcz7XuZl5pENWZ939/Zp8ubGpqkggKMakogfd7bjnbiRaJjGZy2p0zTkkX0qALeEhcxXDUM2ZBXguGNtleUMWHhjIU13HV3fbDVEiYNi4qEzCSCc8ob3TcVw1ZTgqviqLDNS51GZI92PlKMg3kqo0PS7IC1lh326Et8NBFmaJIs5p3gHfx8sJBY6/kuRlqpcfw9ckouaGlZZo5FEBRjhfPgb)

Comment: @tsh If you use `parseFloat`(as there's case `1.5K` they're same length)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 100 bytes

```ruby
~/.$/
i,n,s,k=0,$_.to_f,' KMG',1024
$&<?A?((n/=k;i+=1)until n<k):n*=k**(s=~/#$&/)
print n,s[i].strip
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxNCoMwGET3OYXQ4F/TxKip2hqkKxfiCUoRuiiEyKeYdNGNR28auplh3sDb3s@PczujmCFFgBiiZUbwRO0yvUgUDGMfEZ7lJcJh2926OAYm9VUdJU/eYNUcQKuTC6RSp2ls5M4OOGQJWjcFNvC@u3pQYze1OieQFxXob@MD4lT4EMXZk7IWle8R8bpq/OJN7v9K9N9ltWoB404w/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 114 bytes

```c
*i=L"KMG",d;c;main(S){float f;for(scanf(S="%f%c",&f,&c);c?f*=1024,c-*i++:f>1023?f/=1024,d=*i++:0;);printf(S,f,d);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNb8IwDL33V1hBoLQE1nawTcsKJ8SBceruqEriEcHSqh8bEuK3d0kpmkYOkd@zn/1sMfkUoh1Ihdoo@Mq0AcwOaueiNtDJO9ls14RJLrijaOqf8ZhnNSDHvKSVyAzSNCFDHArCRshGwudiiUEShfGMiUmgx@NXXFj0uMSHKyuTjg25z4tSm9p2YMikzy/toDHWS2fEG2gjjo1U8FbVUufT/cL7zrWEsjFU7LMygJMPZw/sw1LlhTKUaDOtTzVhQH7G9ndC4/NrTdHUFT3dkZVSB6AdxSBkkK5Wm126@ujzfxdIbFIkYS@73YhGdpQLSC/ohhCHLp5drduEOpvONZlH8a3QYqAk3vzH0fYOT@P1HRPOXubPT92E9hc)

Thank ceilingcat for -11 bytes

Comment: @ceilingcat Fail on `512`, output `inf`

Comment: @ceilingcat First argument of `main` is 1, but now the arg has its use